# Haskell: How to recognize a curried function?

Tags: haskell, currying

Given the following two functions:

```
minCur a = (\b -> if a > b then b else a)

minCur a b = if a > b then b else a
```

Asking for the type results for both the same:

```
minCur :: Ord p => p -> p -> p
```

How does the User of the function know if he is dealing with a curried function? Does it even matter?

Edit:

Is this currying?

```
minCur (a,b) = if a > b then b else a
```

Comment: Haskell functions are always curried.

Comment: I edited my question see the last example

Comment: I added some more detail to my answer @simplesystems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the libraries, we have a function `curry` which transforms

```
f :: (A,B) -> C
f (a,b) = ...
```

into `g = curry f`, defined as

```
g :: A -> B -> C
g a b = ...
```

We also have the inverse transformation, called `uncurry` which maps `g` back into `f = uncurry g`.

Sometimes, functions like `g` are called "curried" and functions like `f` are called "uncurried". This way of speaking is a bit informal since we should instead say, more properly, "`g` is the curried form of `f`" and "`f` is the uncurried form of `g`".

There is no perfect distinction between "curried" and "uncurried" functions on ther own. For instance, `h :: (A,B) -> C -> D` can be seen as the currying of `h1 :: ((A,B),C) -> D` or the uncurrying of `h2 :: A -> B -> C -> D`, so it would be both curried and uncurred at the same time.

Often, though, we say that a function is curried or not depending on whether it takes a tuple as a single argument or its components as separate arguments. Again, this is a bit informal.

When choosing which style to follow, in Haskell we prefer the curried form since it is easier to apply partially.

Comment: is there a possibility to see the source of those library functions?

Comment: Since it's open source, you can find it online. But a function like `uncurry` would probably looks like `uncurry f (a, b) = f a b` and `curry` would look like `curry f a b = f (a, b)`

Comment: @simplesystems Use https://hoogle.haskell.org/ to search any library function, and then click on the "source" link next to the function type.

Answer (score 4):

It does not matter, since **every** function that takes more than one argument is a curried function. In Haskell, every function takes a single parameter and returns a single value (`a -> b -> c` is the same as `a -> (b -> c)`).

There shouldn't be a reason for the user to care whether the function is curried or not.

The two function definitions you provided are considered to be the same function. The user shouldn't need to care beyond what the behavior of `minCur` is and what type it has.

In the case of the version with the tuple, it has a different type. So

```
 min (a, b) = if a > b then b else a
 min :: Ord p => (p, p) -> p
```

And the types `(a, a) -> a` and `a -> a -> a` are incompatible. You cannot curry the function with the tuple because it only has one parameter anyway and does not return a function type.

Comment: Really, every function is curried?

Comment: Yes. The way the language sees it is that every function takes in one parameter and gives one output `minCur a b = ...` is syntactic sugar for `minCur = \a -> (\b -> ...` There is no such thing as an uncurried function (the only way to simulate this is with tuples/product types, so the user has to provide one value with all of the data at once. `min (a, b) = ...`

Comment: ah I just edited the question so the Tuple input wouldn't be a curried function? Or is it just a function which doesnt make use of currying?

Comment: I see where you're going with this answer, but “every function is curried” just doesn't make sense as such. A function that only takes one primitive argument and gives one primitive result can't possibly be curried or uncurried. The crucial point is that in Haskell, _every_ function only takes a single argument and gives a single result, but neither of these needs to be primitive.

Comment: So the statement, every function is curried is not correct? Is it better to say Every function in Haskell takes just one argument?

Comment: @leftaroundabout where did I state that the types had to be primitive?